# join query in Magento-2?

Tags: database, magento2.2, php-7

I want get category name from getCollectionTitle() and get question, answer from getCollection().

```
namespace Xxx\ManageFaqs\Block;
    use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context;
    use Xxx\ManageFaqs\Model\FaqcatFactory;
    use Xxx\ManageFaqs\Model\Post;
    use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;
    use Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection;



 class Faq extends Template
    {

        protected $_resource;

        public function __construct(Context $context, FaqcatFactory $modelFactory, ResourceConnection $resource, Post $model)
        {
            $this->model = $model;
            $this->modelFactory = $modelFactory;
            $this->_resource = $resource;
            parent::__construct($context);
        }



  public function getCollection()
    {
         $connection = $this->model->getCollection();
    $connection->addFieldToFilter('category_name', array(1));
    $connection->setOrder('position', 'DESC');
    return $connection;
}




    public function getCollectionTitle()
    {
        $collection = $this->modelFactory->create()->getCollection();
        $second_table_name = $this->_resource->getTableName('faq_category_description');

$collection->getSelect()->join(array('second' => $second_table_name),'main_table.id = second.category_name',[])
                ->where("second.category_name = '1'")->group("second.category_name");

        return $collection;
    }

}
```

***view.phtml***

```
<?php
$collection = $this->getCollection();
$collectionTitle = $this->getCollectionTitle();
?>

 <div id="element" data-mage-init='{"accordion":{"openedState": "active", "collapsible": true, "active": false, "multipleCollapsible": true}}'>


        <div data-role="collapsible">
        <div data-role="trigger">
            <span><?php foreach ($collectionTitle as $item): ?>    
    <?php echo $item->getCategoryName(); ?> 
<?php endforeach; ?></span>
        </div>
    </div>    
<div data-role="content">
<?php foreach ($collection as $item): ?>    
    <?php echo $item->getQuestion(); ?> 
    <?php echo $item->getAnswer(); ?> 
<?php endforeach; ?> </div>
```

How to get category name from **faq_category** and question, answer from **faq_category_description** dynamically.How to optimise this code.

If anyone knows explain me!!!

Comment: Once you get a working answer of your question, after that for your another question you should post another question instead of keep updating the first question

Answer (score 1):

Below code might help you in joining the tables.Now you have to first inject your `FAQ_Category` model to get collection and resource Connection to get `faq_category_description` table name.

```
    public function __construct(
       ...
       \Vendor\ModuleName\Model\FirstFactory $FirstModelFactory,
       \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection $resource
    ) {
       ...
       $this->modelFactory = $FirstModelFactory;
       $this->_resource = $resource;
       ...
    }
```

Now in any of your function join your table as per below code:-

```
     public function getCollectionTitle()
    {
        $collection = $this->modelFactory->create()->getCollection();
        $second_table_name = $this->_resource->getTableName('faq_category_description');

$collection->getSelect()->join(array('second' => $second_table_name),'main_table.id = second.category_name',[])
  ->group("second.category_name");

        return $collection;
    }
      public function getCollection($categoryname)
      {
         $connection = $this->model->getCollection();
         $connection->addFieldToFilter('category_name', $categoryname);
         $connection->setOrder('position', 'DESC');
         return $connection;
      }
```

In **view.phtml** file

```
<?php
$collectionTitle = $this->getCollectionTitle();
?>

 <div id="element" data-mage-init='{"accordion":{"openedState": "active", "collapsible": true, "active": false, "multipleCollapsible": true}}'>
        <div data-role="collapsible">
        <div data-role="trigger">
            <span><?php foreach ($collectionTitle as $item): ?>    
                     <?php echo $item->getCategoryName(); ?>
                    <?php $collection =$this->getCollection($item->getCategoryName());?>
               <div data-role="content">
                  <?php foreach ($collection as $item): ?>    
                     <?php echo $item->getQuestion(); ?> 
                     <?php echo $item->getAnswer(); ?> 
                <?php endforeach; ?> 
             </div>
         <?php endforeach; ?>
        </span>
 </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: it prints second table data.but i want main table data.

Comment: can you please show me the output of this query ?

Comment: it retrieve (output) categoryname from faq_category_description table.I want categoryname from faq_category table.

Comment: see my updated post. you will get only first main table data.

Comment: yes.it's working correctly.How to get category name dynamically.

Comment: can you elaborate  on what bases you need data?

Comment: Please see my updated post

Comment: how to get category name from faq_category and question,answer from faq_category_description dynamically.How to optimise this code.

Comment: Please see updated post

Comment: excepted output:category_name1 questions under this category category_name2:question   category_name3:question......it's all  get from table dynamically

Comment: above query returns single category_name and corresponding questions.how to get all category_name and corresponding questions

Comment: see updated post. remove where condition from getCollectionTitle() function